# Programming Language used in GIS

Tags: geocoding

I am from the Computer application background and want to know that which programming language is being widely used these days in the GIS domain? And what will be it's scope in the future?
How can I utilize my coding skills and contribute to the GIS community?

Also, is Node.js or Java used in this domain?

Comment: In my experience, Python (for working with data) and Javascript (for web design) are two commonly-used languages.

Comment: You can work on solving bugs and developing new features for QGIS, which is an open-source GIS software. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: Unlike discussion groups, GIS SE uses a Focused question/Best answer model. Questions which compile lists, ask for opinions, or seek general advice are off-topic here, and are likely to be closed.  While we do have [chat] for this kind of discussion, Chat is *underutilized*, so you may be better off seeking a true discussion site for discussion-oriented questions.

Comment: SQL for spatial data is more common language for analysis as well as processing of data, which can be best seen in PostgreSQL with PostGIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python offers extensive libraries for geospatial applications (like `shapely`, `fiona` and `geopandas`) and is most widely used. You can also use Python in QGIS and create plugins for QGIS using the `PyQt` package. Python seems to be the most used in the GIS community.

A lot of people also use the POSTGIS extension to Postgresql to do geospatial analysis.

There are also some libraries in R if you are familiar with that (`rgdal`, `sp` and `rgeos`).

If you are more familiar with another language, you can also try and contribute to geospatial libraries in that particular language.

Comment: For QGIS and Python, a good starting point is to have look [on this material](https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/pyqgis-in-a-day.html) from Ujaval Gandhi and [this one](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/) from @underdark